# How to store the output of type function in python and use it in 'if' condition?

Tags: python

How can we store the output of 'type' function in a variable ?

```
next = raw_input('> ')
type = type(next)

if type == 'int':
   val = int(next)
else:
   print "Type a number!"
```

Syntax Error at line 4....?

Comment: You can't use `type` that way - it will always be `str` because thats what raw_input returns. You could use just `input`

Comment: `input` will only work that way in python 2.

Comment: (also `input`'s a huge security vulnerability)

Comment: @muddyfish just realized that and updated my answer. I wonder why they removed that in python 3 :)

Comment: You may find this helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23294658/asking-the-user-for-input-until-they-give-a-valid-response

Comment: BTW, overwriting the built-in functions [`next`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html#next) and [`type`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html#type) is a very very bad idea.

Comment: Well.., I figured out that I just can't use "type" as a name for any variable because it is an inbuilt python keyword.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several ways of doing what you want. Note that defining a `type` variable to mask the `type` function is not good practice! (and next either BTW :))

```
n = raw_input('> ')  # (or input in python 3)

try: 
   val = int(n)
except ValueError:
   print("Type a number!")
```

or

```
n = raw_input('> ')  # (or input in python 3)

if n.isdigit():
   val = int(n)
else:
   print("Type a number!")
```

Note: as some comment indicated, that in python 2, it was possible to get what you wanted by just using

```
n = input("> ")
```

but very ill adviced since you have to control what `n` is really, not python 3 portable, and has huge security issues:

Ex: in python 2 on windows, try that:

```
import os
n = input("> ")
```

and type `os.system("notepad")`

you'll get a nice `notepad` windows !! You see that it is really not recommended to use `input` (imagine I type `os.system("del <root of your system>")`) ...

Comment: good find! My bad!

Comment: `int("3.5")` throws `ValueError` too. but `isdigit` is singular!! fixed!